# How can we actually prove that photon is its own antiparticle?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter

As we know that photon is its own antiparticle so how can we confidently say this is true? Is there any theory that describes it?

Comment: That is a necessary feature of, for instance, QED which is the physical theory that can lay claim to the most precisely tested agreement between theory and experiment in all of science. That's pretty much as good as 'proof' gets. This isn't mathematics.

Comment: @dmckee so there is explanation of light or not??

Comment: Yes. Quantum ElectroDymanics (QED) is the theory of light in terms of photons.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the standard model. But experimentally, two photons may collide to form an electron-positron pair.

Comment: A single photon can spontaneously convert to an electron-positron pair under certain conditions, so this proves nothing about the anti-particle of the photon.

Comment: @StephenG not on its own, while conserving energy and momentum. But the point of two photons colliding to form an electron position pair is that photon number is clearly not a conserved quantity, unlike lepton numbers (with a bit of flooding over vector bosons in weak interactions)

Comment: @dr-xorile You're missing the point.  The production of a pair of antiparticles by a photon or multiple photons does *not* imply anything about a photon being it's own anti-particle (or otherwise).

Comment: @StephenG so it is not confirmed that photon has it's antiparticle Right?

Comment: I would say we had no evidence at this time that the photon's antiparticle is not a photon.

Comment: @StephenG so is it wrong to say that light is made up of combination of photon and anti photon?

Comment: It's not exactly wrong, but it's misleading in that you may give the impression that there is a difference between the photo and it's anti-particle.

Comment: @mentalshakya The standard theory describing light and how it interacts with matter, QED, says that the photon is its own antiparticle, and there is zero evidence contradicting this. All the predictions of QED match observations extremely well, so we have great confidence in it.

Comment: A collision of two photons producing an electron-positron pair has not been experimentally observed to date.

Comment: Maybe in future it will be @safesphere

Answer (score -3):

Due to the photon being electrically neutral, it can be said to be its own antiparticle, given that an antiparticle has the opposite charge as the original particle.

Comment: Neutrinos are  electrically neutral, but there is a clear distinction between neutrinos and anti-neutrinos

Comment: @PhillS is there any relation between photon and neutrinos.?

Comment: NaturalNonThinker, your post attempts to draw a straight line between neutrality and a particle being it's own antiparticle. Any clear counter example calls that in to question. Mind you, I would have used the neutron or the neutral kaon as an example because the Fermi or Majorana character of the neutrino is still a matter of inquiry and if they are Majoranic (as predicted by the standard model) they would not represent a good example. @PhillS

Comment: So what is the good example @dmckee

Comment: The neutron or the neutral kaon. Just like I said.